# Horizontal align for dynamic content (special case)

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu (header menu) in my web page which is actually takes dynamic content. The dynamic menu items are loaded into `ul>li>{dynamic_content}`. I want this navigation bar (I mean the `ul` ) in the **center** of the section, not vertically but horizontally. I can have `text-align:center` because it has multiple children tags.

Also I can't do the following,

```
.class{
  width:50%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
 }
```

because I can't set a `width` since this is a DYNAMIC navigation.

You may think why I can't try

```
.class{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
 }
```

This is also can not be done, because I can't set the `position:absolute` since it's going to be a fixed header on scroll. It make some position problems in responsive.

I'm looking for an alternative to solve this problem.

Comment: Answered my own question. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out a new way to align contents Horizontally.This works nice to me and have no issue with browser compatibility.

Wrapped the navigation with a `div` and set `text-align:center` and added `display:inline-block` to the `ul` that I wanted to center.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content: center` from **flexbox**.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Title 1</span>
  <span>Title 2</span>
  <span>Title 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But I am not sure that `flex` is comfortable with other browsers like **IE or EDGE**.

Comment: @Ramesh - Till what version of IE are you looking to provide support for?

Comment: Version from 6 to the latest

Comment: Is there any other way that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox to center the list on the page will work.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does `flexbox` support in browsers like **IE/EDGE**?

Comment: IE11 is not a problem. Anything below that won't work. IE10 has it's own syntax. EDGE is ok.

Comment: But I am looking for version 6 and up :-( sadly `flexbox` never help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for old browsers support, another option would be using display table as it is explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

```css
.something-semantic {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.something-else-semantic {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="something-semantic">
   <div class="something-else-semantic">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is only supporting for a single child DOM. I trie with the `li` as parent and `a` as child. It worked. But I want the `ul` to be centered. `ul` as parent and `li` tags are as childs.